# Python: How do I make voice control working while music is playing?

Tags: python, multithreading, audio, fft, voice-recognition

I am working on a voice controlled home assistant in python3.
On startup a thread is created that listens for voice input from the user.
The listen() method is using google voice recognition and passes the text to a method for parsing the speech and executing requests from the user.

```
class ListenThread(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListenThread, self).__init__()
        self._stop_event = threading.Event()
        self._deaf_event = threading.Event()

    def run(self):

        while not self.stopped():
            if self.deaf():
                print('sleeping')
                sleep(5)
                print('waking up')
                self._deaf_event.clear()
            #   Change for silent / listening mode
            # listen_keyboard()
            listen()

    def deafen(self, time):
        self._deaf_event.set()

    def deaf(self):
        return self._deaf_event.is_set()

    def stop(self):
        self._stop_event.set()

    def stopped(self):
        return self._stop_event.is_set()
```

If the user did not start the request with the needed code word, like "Alexa" on Amazon echo or "Okay Google" on google assistant, the thread sleeps for 5 seconds and listens again afterwards. This prevents executing wrong requests.

So far so good.
The problem is that while playing music the thread tends to use the played audio as audio input and either sleeps for 5 seconds over and over again or mixes the real voice input with the played song which ultimately leads to sleeping again because of the invalid request from the user.
I figured that would be the problem because the thread works just fine in "silent mode" where the input comes from the keyboard and not from the microphone.

The only thing that comes to my mind to fix this problem would be subtracting the audio from the music track from the whole audio input with mixed audio from the users voice and the song itself. We did have a bit of fourier transform etc in university lately but that seems to be a bit over the top. Do you have any other idea how to solve this?